# replace of menu item position by another menu item position in same menu

Tags: android, menu

I am trying to create a context menu for card view.Initial menu like 
**fig 1:** initial context menu

[image]

and i need to replace it like **fig 2:** replaced context menu

[image]

.When i click on disable menu the card view will be disabled,and the disable menu should replace with enable menu

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To help other users help you, please provide an explanation of what you have tried already, that didn't work. Smaller images (or links to images) might be better too, to not clutter the screen. Please try to improve your question to get better help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call invalidateOptionsMenu() after click on menu item to change menu item title.

```
Boolean IsEnable = false;

@Override
public boolean onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuItem reminderstatus = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.reminderstatus);
    if (IsEnable) {
        reminderstatus.setTitle("Disable");
    } else {
        reminderstatus.setTitle("Enable");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.reminderstatus) {
        if (IsEnable) {
            IsEnable = false;
        } else {
            IsEnable = true;
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }
}
```

Comment: i need context menu not options menu

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to create Different Menu item for Enable and Disable , take a single menu-item , just change the text of menu item , from their Status (Enable or Disable).
hope you are saving status that currently it is Enable or Disable.

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);

    // Select a menu item then change it's title (text)
    MenuItem mi = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.YOUR_MENU_ID);
    if(CHECK_YOUE_CURRENT_STATUS_HERE){

      //SET YOUR CURRENT STATUS ACCORDINGLY CURRENT STATUS (ENABLE /DISABLE)
      mi.setTitle("Enable/Disable");

    }
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.reminderstatus) {
        if (YOUR_CURRENT_STATUS) {
            YOUR_CURRENT_STATUS = false;
        } else {
            YOUR_CURRENT_STATUS = true;
        }
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    //this method refresh your Context menu view so basically call 
    // your onCreateContextMenu once again which will check for your 
    // Status and set accordingly it.
        }
    }
```

Just check this sample code implement it correctly will work for you.

Comment: i have one question,for example when you first tap on the card view the fig 1 will appear and re-clicking on  fig 2 has to appear.how can you code.sorry to again ask .